# GRUB menu lost after Windows 11 update

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-11

I am dual booting Windows 11 and Ubuntu on a GPD Pocket 3 i7 (on the same disc). I almost exclusively use Ubuntu on this machine. In anticipation of a meeting with a client where I would need a windows pc, I booted into Windows and updated it.
After rebooting, I lost my GRUB menu and the system boots directly into Windows. Following, the most upvoted answer on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1383643/grub-menu-after-upgrade-to-windows-11) similar but not same question, I tried changing the boot order in UEFI. To no avail. Do I need to reinstall GRUB?

Comment: Are you able to directly boot Ubuntu from UEFI boot menu, often f12 but varies by vendor? Same key you use to boot live installers. Did Windows also turn fast startup and UEFI Secure boot? Check settings.

Comment: @oldfred No I am not able to directly boot Ubuntu (This is what I meant with my last statement). It does not seem that fast startup was reenabled (it is not available as an option in "Define power buttons and turn on power protection".)

Comment: @oldfed Thank you for making me boot into UEFI again. I had confused boot order (the disks), with boot order (the boot manager on the disk). Gonna delete this as it seems my wuestion is a dulpicate...